# How to find usage of a particular resource id or layout in the project of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to find usage of resource id (action_my_tokens) in the project that where it is used in the project.

Here is a xml file which shows code. How can I do this?

**Here is the code of xml :**

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_send"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_send"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_my_address"
    android:icon="@mipmap/qr_code_icon"
    android:title="@string/title_request"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_my_tokens"
    android:icon="@drawable/token_icon"
    android:title="@string/title_tokens" />
```

Answer (score 6):

> Right click on this layout in  **action_my_tokens.xml** in Android
>   Studio and popup comes tap on **Find Usages** .

Bottom of the Android Studio you will get **Find usages of in All Places**

Then inside that you will get the Java File/layout with uses count. If you use this xml to more then one java classes or xml/layouts it will show you.